# custom breakpoint not working in flexlayout

Tags: angular-flex-layout

I am trying to set different background color for different resolution mode using flexlayout.

its not working, below is my code

app.component.html

```
<div class="content" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxFlexFill >
          <div fxFlex="50" [fxFlex.xs]="xsBGColor" [fxFlex.md]="mdBGColor">
              first-section
          </div>
          <div fxFlex="50" [fxFlex.xs]="xsBGColor"  [fxFlex.md]="mdBGColor">
              second-section
          </div>
</div>
```

app.component.css

```
.xsBGColor{
background-color:red;
}
.mdBGColor{
background-color:blue;
}
```

some thing i missed here but i cant find, please suggest what i missed in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ngClass` instead of `fxFlex`

`ngClass.xs="xsBGColor"`

Ref: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/ngClass-API